# Is there a way to define alternative conversion functions (from/to interfaces) in a protobuf-net surrogate class

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Using protobuf-net v2 build 668, I’m trying to serialize/deserialize a class which contains a member defined as an interface while doing on-the-fly conversions at the same time.
Normally, the surrogate approach would work just fine but since C# doesn’t allow user-defined conversions for interfaces, I can’t define the conversions.

Thanks,

```
namespace ProtoBufNetTest
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;

    using ProtoBuf;
    using ProtoBuf.Meta;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IDummy), false)
                .SetSurrogate(typeof(DummySurrogate));

            var container = new Container { Data = new Dummy { Positive = 3 } };

            using (var file = File.Create("test.bin"))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(file, container);
            }

            using (var file = File.OpenRead("test.bin"))
            {
                container = Serializer.Deserialize<Container>(file);
                Debug.Assert(container.Data.Positive == 3);
            }
       }
    }

    // Outside of the project, cannot be changed
    public interface IDummy
    {
        int Positive { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Container
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public IDummy Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Dummy : IDummy
    {
        public int Positive { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class DummySurrogate
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Negative { get; set; }

        // Does not compile : user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed
        public static explicit operator IDummy(DummySurrogate value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new Dummy { Positive = -value.Negative };
        }

        // Does not compile : user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed
        public static explicit operator DummySurrogate(IDummy value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new DummySurrogate { Negative = -value.Positive };
        }

        // Fake attribute, does not exist but could work if it did
        [ProtoConvertFrom]
        public static IDummy From(DummySurrogate value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new Dummy { Positive = -value.Negative };
        }

        // Fake attribute, does not exist but could work if it did
        [ProtoConvertTo]
        public static DummySurrogate To(IDummy value)
        {
            return value == null ? null : new DummySurrogate { Negative = -value.Positive };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to say: I'm not ignoring you - due to a house move I have limited PC time today. Will get back to you asap

Comment: Thanks Marc. Good luck with the move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current build: no, there is not.

However, in the next build, this works fine:

```
[ProtoContract]
class DummySurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Negative { get; set; }

    [ProtoConverter]
    public static IDummy From(DummySurrogate value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : new Dummy { Positive = -value.Negative };
    }

    [ProtoConverter]
    public static DummySurrogate To(IDummy value)
    {
        return value == null ? null : new DummySurrogate
           { Negative = -value.Positive };
    }
}
```

Basically, a `static` method marked `[ProtoConverter]` takes precedence over an `implicit` or `explicit` conversion operator that is defined, with the further advantage that `[ProtoConverter]` methods are not subject to the same syntactic rules as operators. It is not necessary to define separate `*To` / `*From` attributes, as the intent is clear from the signature.

As a side note: the attributes on `Dummy` are unnecessary and are never used.

Comment: That's perfect. Looking forward to the next build. Thanks a lot. Franck

Comment: I removed the attributes on Dummy to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Marc, it seems this build has never been released to NuGet, are there any plans for it or should I build protobuf-net from the source?

Comment: @JulienLebosquain I've been tied up with a load of other things, but I hope to work on protobuf-net towards the end of next week (I'm all tied up until Wednesday)